# Export HTML to PDF in angular2 using angular1 example of plunker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular

I found a simple Export to PDF on Plunker, here is the link: https://plnkr.co/edit/HmKBjYmJNjp8mPzIlg52?p=preview

I am trying to use the same but in angular2, as I am in angular2 I am confused in calling the function which is used in exporting to PDF, below is my code. In html it's of **export-data.component.html** and in JS it's of **export-data.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-export-data',
  templateUrl: './export-data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./export-data.component.css']
})
export class ExportDataComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

    reportData = [
                     {
                         "EmployeeID": "1234567",
                         "LastName": "Lastname",
                         "FirstName": "First name",
                         "Salary": 1000
                     },
                     {
                         "EmployeeID": "11111111",
                         "LastName": "Lastname 1",
                         "FirstName": "First name 1",
                         "Salary": 2000
                     }
    ];

    exportActionPDF(){
      
    }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    
  <!--  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../exportlibrary/style.css" /> -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.10/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.10"></script>
    
    <script src="../../exportlibrary/tableExport.js"></script>
    <script src="../../exportlibrary/app/jquery.base64.js"></script>
    <script src="../../exportlibrary/app/sprintf.js"></script>
    <script src="../../exportlibrary/app/jspdf.js"></script>
    <script src="../../exportlibrary/app/base64.js"></script>
    
   
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Export HTML Table to Excel, Pdf, CSV and Doc</p>
    
    <table class="export-table" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 20px">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Employee ID</th>
                  <th>Last Name</th>
                  <th>First Name</th>
                  <th>Salary</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
             <!-- <tr ng-repeat="item in reportData"> -->
                 <tr *ngFor="let item of reportData">
                  <td>{{item.EmployeeID}}</td>
                  <td>{{item.LastName}}</td>
                  <td>{{item.FirstName}}</td>
                  <td>{{item.Salary}}</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <a href="#" data-ng-click="exportAction('csv')"> Export CSV</a><br/><br/>
    <a href="#" data-ng-click="exportAction('excel')"> Export Excel</a><br/><br/>
    <a href="#" data-ng-click="exportAction('doc')"> Export Doc</a><br/><br/>
    <a href="#" (click)="exportActionPDF"> Export Pdf</a><br/><br/>
  </body>

</html>
```

I want to understand as per the link shared above, what should I write inside the `exportActionPDF` function so that it exports?

Below is the screenshot of my HTML page:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should call jquery plugin `tableExport`. Here is an example:

```
declare let $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <table #table class="export-table" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 20px">
      <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Employee ID</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of reportData">
          <td>{{item.EmployeeID}}</td>
          <td>{{item.LastName}}</td>
          <td>{{item.FirstName}}</td>
          <td>{{item.Salary}}</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
  <a href="#" (click)="exportActionPDF(table)"> Export Pdf</a><br/><br/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  reportData = [
    {
      "EmployeeID": "1234567",
      "LastName": "Lastname",
      "FirstName": "First name",
      "Salary": 1000
    },
    {
      "EmployeeID": "11111111",
      "LastName": "Lastname 1",
      "FirstName": "First name 1",
      "Salary": 2000
    }
  ];

  exportActionPDF(table){
    $(table).tableExport({ type: 'pdf', escape: false });
  }
}
```

Notice i use **[template reference variable](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars)**

```
<table #table
```

to get reference to `table` html element and pass it to `exportActionPDF` method. You can also use `@ViewChild` instead.

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/WLVNZfAnBokhKcDUihDN?p=preview)**

Comment: If i need to add an image or some other paragraph, then ? if i am understanding right, then you are binding it to a table using template reference ? and why do we need to use `declare let $: any;` this, can you guide please..

Comment: I use `declare let $: any;` to silence typescript compiler

Comment: If you want to add an image or something else you should read `jspdf` documentation

Comment: yes because without this, it gives some error and what to do if i need to add a paragraph of text or an image above the table ? as i see you have binded it with #table

Comment: I binded it with `#table` to get `HTMLTableElement` because `tableExport` plugin expects table element